# Splitting Strings by slashes

Tags: string, qt, split

I'm just wondering how i can split a string by both front slashes (/) & backslashes (). So for example, these types of strings;

```
"X:/Blah/blah/"
"X:\Blah\blah\"
```

And also mixed slashes;

```
"X:/Blah\blah/"
```

Would work & in each case return:
   "X:", "Blah", "blah"

I believe i will need to use a QRegExp, http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qregexp.html but i'm just not sure what character set i will need to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
str.split( QRegExp("[/\\\\]") );
```

The regex needs two backslashes to prevent the backslash character from escaping the `]` character, and C++ adds an additional two so that you're passing in `\` literals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it does not support backslahes. Only forward slashes. How can i get the back slash support as-well?

Comment: I see what i did wrong. I was supplying strings with just one backslash in my path. Thus that was getting ignored. Ah well, i decided to just replace everything to backslashes in the end anyway, but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are parsing file names, how about using QFileInfo?

```
QFileInfo fileInfo("c:\\test folder\\one\\test\\three.avi");
```

That will convert everything to forward slashes. When you output the absolute path:

```
qDebug() << fileInfo.absolutePath();
```

The output will just have forward slashes like this:

```
"C:/test folder/one/test"
```

You can then use the regular split command as so to get the components:

```
QStringList fileParts = fileInfo.absolutePath().split("/");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since regular expressions can beexpensive to evaluate, maybe a better solution would be replacing the characters and then split (assuming the regex does not get more complicated).

```
QString string = someFilePath();
//replace one char with another, requires no memory allocation
string.replace('\\', '/', Qt::CaseSensitive);
//you may want to use QString::KeepEmptyParts instead
QStringList pathElements = string.split('/', QString::SkipEmptyParts, Qt::CaseSensitive);
```

This way there is no need to compile a regular expression and evaluate it. This should make it a bit faster. Also `QRegExp` is not the best regular expresion implementation, which is why in Qt 5 there is a new class `QRegularExpression` which uses `PCRE` internally.