# Slice Qstring from right hand side

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a qstring of directory structure and need to take the second last element after "/" into a new qstring

```
"C:/Users/emb/Documents/AutoConnectTest/02/Job_0"
```

How to save 02 into a new QString

Comment: You need to use a regex or split - string.split('/'). Look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353306/splitting-strings-by-slashes

Comment: For crying out loud, don't do path manipulation using strings! Use QFileInfo, QDir and the proper functions to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QString split function.

[Splits the string into substrings wherever sep occurs, and returns the list of those strings.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split)

this code split all section by "/" and merge two second from last.

```
QString string = "C:/Users/emb/Documents/AutoConnectTest/02/Job_0"; 
QStringList lst = string.split('/');
qDebug() << lst[lst.count()-2] + "/" + lst[lst.count()-1];
```

**Output**:

```
"02/Job_0"
```